# when i record video with javacv it comes "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil"

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I make a video recorder android app with javacv.
But, when i run this app this error occurs "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil".

How can I solve this error?

gradle.build file

```
  android {
   ..............
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        pickFirst  'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
        pickFirst  'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'
        pickFirst  'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
        pickFirst  'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'

}
```

My demo code  **VideoService** which will invoke in MainActivity

```
package com.fs.fs.api;

import com.fs.fs.App;
import com.fs.fs.utils.DateUtils;
import com.fs.fs.utils.FileUtils;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by wyx on 2017/1/11.
 */
public class VideoService {
    private FFmpegFrameRecorder mFrameRecorder;
    private String path;

    private VideoService() {
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final VideoService INSTANCE = new VideoService();
    }

    public static VideoService getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void startRecordVideo() {
        String fileName = String.format("%s.%s", DateUtils.date2String(new Date(), "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"), "mp4");
        path = FileUtils.getExternalFullPath(App.getInstance(), fileName);
        mFrameRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path, 640, 480, 1);
        mFrameRecorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        mFrameRecorder.setVideoOption("tune", "zerolatency");
        mFrameRecorder.setVideoOption("preset", "ultrafast");
        mFrameRecorder.setVideoOption("crf", "28");
        mFrameRecorder.setVideoBitrate(300 * 1000);
        mFrameRecorder.setFormat("mp4");

        mFrameRecorder.setFrameRate(30);
        mFrameRecorder.setAudioOption("crf", "0");
        mFrameRecorder.setSampleRate(48 * 1000);
        mFrameRecorder.setAudioBitrate(960 * 1000);
        mFrameRecorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
        try {
            mFrameRecorder.start();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mFrameRecorder != null) {
            try {
                mFrameRecorder.stop();
                mFrameRecorder.release();
            } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mFrameRecorder = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.fs.fs.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.fs.fs.R;
import com.fs.fs.api.VideoService;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        VideoService.getInstance().startRecordVideo();
        try {
            sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        VideoService.getInstance().stop();
    }
}
```

Error

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.usb, PID: 660
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:590)
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1694)
                      at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149)
                      at com.fs.fs.api.VideoService.startRecordVideo(VideoService.java:34)
                      at com.fs.fs.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5304)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1694) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149) 
                      at com.fs.fs.api.VideoService.startRecordVideo(VideoService.java:34) 
                      at com.fs.fs.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5304) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1694) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149) 
                      at com.fs.fs.api.VideoService.startRecordVideo(VideoService.java:34) 
                      at com.fs.fs.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5304) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fs.fs-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fs.fs-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1694) 
                      at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149) 
                      at com.fs.fs.api.VideoService.startRecordVideo(VideoService.java:34) 
                      at com.fs.fs.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5304) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i solve this error?

Why error occurs?

Comment: Please try a more recent version. That issue should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, I try with the newer version and it done.